# Facing Error for Flutter_stripe :Execution failed for task ':stripe_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: flutter, compiler-errors, flutter-dependencies, flutter-stripe, flutter-pub

```
Execution failed for task ':stripe_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> error: invalid source release: 17
```

I am facing this error in flutter_stripe , I am not getting how to solve it. I upgrade the jdk but it does't work , Please help me I am stucked for several hours

**android\build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.22'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Please help me

I upgrade the jdk from 17 to 21 and also upgrade kotlin version but it doen't work